# Animate.css doesn't work on Owl Carousel slide transition

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, animate.css

I created a slide using Owl Carousel. As you can see, I imported both Owl and animate.css CDN's:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" integrity="sha512-c42qTSw/wPZ3/5LBzD+Bw5f7bSF2oxou6wEb+I/lqeaKV5FDIfMvvRp772y4jcJLKuGUOpbJMdg/BTl50fJYAw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
```

Here is Owl Carousel HTML code:

```
<div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="section6-item">
                    <img class="pr-6" src="../img/slide1.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>                    </div>
                <div class="section6-item">
                    <img class="pr-6" src="../img/slide2.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section6-item">
                    <img class="pr-6" src="../img/slide3.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section6-item">
                    <img src="../img/slide4.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-arrows">
                <button class="btn-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
                <button class="btn-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is JQuery code for Owl carousel with animateIn and animateOut:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
margin: 10,
animateOut: 'rollOut',
animateIn: 'rollIn',
responsive: {
    0: {
        items: 1,
        center:true,
        loop:true
    },
    600: {
        items: 1,
        center: true,
        loop: true
    },
    1000: {
        items: 1,
        center:true,
        loop: true
    }
}
```

});

Problem is that AnimateIn and AnimateOut don't work, please help me, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to include jquery and the settings of carousel are not correct.
This works.

```js
$(function() {
  // Owl Carousel
  var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    animateOut: "rollOut",
    animateIn: "rollIn",
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="section6-item">
      <img class="pr-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" srcset="">
      <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section6-item">
      <img class="pr-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" srcset="">
      <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section6-item">
      <img class="pr-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" srcset="">
      <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section6-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" srcset="">
      <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-arrows">
    <button class="btn-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button class="btn-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```